# How get changeable autolayout UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, interface-builder

I try to create UIView with auto layout constraints in Interface Builder, it's height will be equal to superview with multiplier 0.5, but if it height is bigger than 500px, it will be 500.
I know that in auto layout equal property there is parameters (>=, ==, <=), maybe that will help me?

[image]

If anyone know how to create something like this, please, write your proposes or examples in answer.
Thanks for all ideas!

Comment: _You_ write _your_ "proposes or examples" in the _question_. Show us what you are trying to do, what your code or constraints are, and what happens when you run the app that differs from what you want.

Comment: @matt, so, now I add equal with multiplier (0.5, <= 500) and add fixed height (>= 500). I think that is not a good example of solving the problem, but it works.
What do you think?
(I will add screenshot in a few minutes)

Comment: Wait. If it works, why is there even a problem?

Comment: @matt, I wrote a question, after have a new idea and this idea in projects works. But question has already asked.

Comment: Well if the problem is solved, delete the question. Inequalities are _exactly_ how you do this: you tell the layout engine what to aim at. That is what an inequality _is_. What else do you want?

Comment: try proportional height to superview with multiplier 0.5 and =0. Height >= 500. and set the constraint priorities low and high respectively